# String型のArrayからDouble型の配列に変換する方法

Tags: ios, swift, mapkit, array

XcodeでSwiftを使い、マップのiOSアプリを製作してます。

MapKitで地図を表示させて、その上に複数のピンを立てるつもりです。
そのピンの位置情報なのですが、緯度、経度の情報が入力されたcsvファイル(00,0000000,000.0000000のような数字のファイル)を読み込み、String型の配列にしたうえで読み込んでいるのですが、位置情報であるCLLocationCoordinate2DMakeの読み込みにはDouble型でなければいけないようです。

そのString型の配列からDouble型の配列に変換する方法がどうしてもわかりません。

解決方法のご存知の方、どうかご教示ください。

(stringの宣言とcsvの読み込み)

```
  //stringの宣言
  var posionStr: [[String]] = []

    //csvの読み込み
    if let csvPath = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("location", ofType: "csv") {
        //初期化
        do {
            let csvString =  try NSString(contentsOfFile: csvPath, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding) as String
            csvString.enumerateLines{ line, stop in
                // 行の途中に","が含まれていたら、配列の要素として切り抜く
                let str2: [String] = line.componentsSeparatedByString(",")
                //切り抜いた要素を追加
                self.posionStr.append(str2)
            }
            // 何かしらのエラーがあると以下に入る
        } catch _ {
            print("何らかのエラーが発生しました")
        }
        print(posionStr)
    }
```

(ピンの位置情報)

```
    locationManager = CLLocationManager()
    locationManager.delegate = self
    self.mapView.delegate = self

    let annotation = MKPointAnnotation()

   //ここで配列から緯度、経度情報を読み込みたい
    annotation.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(posionStr[0][1].latitude,posionStr[0][2].longitude)
    self.mapView.addAnnotation(annotation)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var posionDouble = Double(posionStr[0][1])
```

このDoubleのイニシアライザの返り値は、Optional型であることは、ごぞんじでしたか？

```
var positionDuble: Double? = Double(positionStr[0][1]) // 注意。これはUnwrappingの構文じゃないよ。
```

おそらくエラーは、非Optional型の変数に、Optional型を代入しようとしたというものだと思われます。（実行時でなく）コンパイル時のエラーだと思われますので、エラーメッセージをよく読んでください。

Optional型の変数から、値を非Optional型の変数に代入する方法は、Swiftの基礎中の基礎なので、すでに質問者さんは学習ずみのはずです。質問者さんが教科書としていた書籍なり電子ブックなりを再度読み直してください。
いちおう代表的な方法をふたつ書いておきます。

*Forced Unwrapping*

```
var positionDouble: Double = Double(positionStr[0][1])!
```

Optional型の変数の末尾に`!`をつけると、非Optional型の値を取り出せます。

*Optional Binding*

```
if var positionDouble = Double(positionStr[0][1]) {

}
```

変数positionDoubleのスコープが`{ ~ }`に限られるので、使い方が限定されます。が、Forced Unwrappingが、もしnilの値に対して行うと、プログラムがクラッシュするのに対し、Optional Bindingは、nilでもクラッシュしないという違いがあります。もしnilだったら、`{ ~ }`が実行されないだけです。（うしろに`else { ~ }`をつけて、nilだった場合の処理を行うこともできます。）

Comment: 指摘のとおり、返り値がoptional型になることの理解が足りなかったようです。

指摘されたコードを入力してみましたが、またもやエラーが出てしまいました。エラーの内容は、
        Cannot invoke initializer for type 'Double' with an argument list of type '([[String]])'
です。
エラーメッセージの意味を調べると、Double型では、String型のイニシャライザーを実行できません。
という意味のようです。

調べたところ、変換しようとしているStringが、Array型で宣言しているのが原因だと気付き、
var str: [[String]] = []
から
var str = String()
に変えたところ、上記のコードが通りました！

よって、重要なのはString型の「配列」からDouble型の「配列」に変換する方法だとわかったので、質問文を大きく変更しました。

Comment: @dobe どうも私の回答を、正しく読んでくれてないようです。回答を更新、拡張しました。「Stringの配列の配列のpositionStrを、Stringとして使ってしまった」というのは、本質的な問題ではありません。Optional型のUnwrapの方法を、教科書で再学習することが、本質だと思われます。